# Why is an Internet URL not working in an iframe tag?

Tags: iframe

My code is working for a local URL, but not for an Internet URL:

```
<div style="margin-top: 8px; display: Block">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="Txtlink" placeholder="Enter or Paste a Link" style="width: 84%; float: left;"><a style="border-radius: 5px; float: right" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="isValidURL()" type="button">Add</a>
    <iframe id="urliframe" src="" width="404" height="250" scrolling="no" style="display:none;">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function isValidURL() {
    var RegExp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
    var url = document.getElementById("Txtlink").value

    if (RegExp.test(url)) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#urliframe").show();
            var loc = url;
            alert(loc);
            document.getElementById('urliframe').setAttribute('src', loc);
        });     
    }
    else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not working".  What does this code do?  When you debug it, where/how specifically does it fail?  Also, formatting your code to be human-readable will help other humans read it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 3rd party site, they may have a denied access by using the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

If it is your site, you may need to set the correct header to allow the page to be visible within the frame.